# reflecting badly on the organization

Tags: charity

A non-profit I volunteer for wants to stop accepting Bitcoin because "it has been in the news a lot negatively and it reflects badly on the organization".  How can I answer this?

Answer (score 4):

Tell them that actions of others doesn't necessarily reflect the organization you're in. Gangsters and drug dealers use USD everyday as well, their wrongdoings are not yours.

Answer (score 2):

I would point out that they are turning away donations. I think the sorts of people that donate BC are probably unlikely to donate if BC is not an option.

However, my biggest suggestion is not to them, but to you: be prepared for the possibility that nothing you say is going to change their mind. Being right is no guarantee that you will be able to convince people.

Remember also, that an organisation's reputation is worth a LOT - they may be right that they will lose more donations than they gain, even if the reason they lose reputation is stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Is Overstock.com "negative"?

If not, they've been [rapidly increasing BTC denominated sales](http://www.foxbusiness.com/technology/2014/03/04/overstock-surpasses-1m-in-bitcoin-purchases/).

The fear of being behind the curve could present a justifiable cost to avoid cryptocurrency denomination.